# Error in using Embeded Firebird

Tags: visual-studio-2010, firebird, firebird2.5, openaccess, telerik-open-access

I used telerik OpenAccess to connect to firebird Database with this ConnectionString :

```
"ServerType=1;User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Dialect=3;Database=TEST.fdb"
```

[image]

and when i want to select my tables  i get this error :
[image]

I download Firebird-2.5.1.26351-0_x64_embed.zip and copy the following File in my output folder:

1. fbembed.dll
2. firebird.conf
3. firebird.msg
4. ib_util.dll
5. icuin30.dll
6. icudt30.dll
7. icuuc30.dll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ClientLibrary` connection string parameter to specify where the fbembed.dll is (or put it into working dir of Telerik OpenAccess.

Comment: I use "ClientLibrary=fbembed.dll" in my connection String but i can't Connect to Database. my Error is : An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect  format.

Comment: You have to put there full path. And make sure you have proper fbembed.dll according to your program - 64bit vs. 32bit.

Comment: my OS is 64 bit and i am using 64bit Firebird.and i use Fullpath for Clientlibrary (for example E:\fbembed.dll) but i still have problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is Telerik OpenAccess also 64-bit? If not, you need to use the 32-bit firebird embedded.

Comment: i use 32bit openaccess and firebird but still i have same problem